Unable to get the updated position of a marker after draggin the marker
I'm unable to update the models with the position when a marker is dragged.
Here is a snippet where the five postions are never updated in the view when I drag a marker.
What is wrong with that code?
Thank you
import dash
from dash import html, Input, Output, State
import dash_leaflet as dl
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# Initialize the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Create initial marker positions
initial_positions = [
    [51.5, -0.1],
    [51.51, -0.09],
    [51.49, -0.08],
    [51.52, -0.07],
    [51.53, -0.06]
]

# Create a function to generate marker elements
def create_marker(lat, lon, idx):
    return dl.Marker(
        id=f"marker-{idx}",
        position=[lat, lon],
        draggable=True
    )

# Layout of the Dash app
app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        html.H1("Draggable Markers on Map"),
        dl.Map(
            children=[
                dl.TileLayer(),
                dl.LayerGroup(id="layer"),
            ],
            style={'width': '100%', 'height': '50vh'},
            center=[51.5, -0.1],
            zoom=13,
            id="map"
        ),
        html.Div(id="output")
    ],
    fluid=True
)

# Callback to update the marker positions and display them
@app.callback(
    Output("layer", "children", allow_duplicate=True),
    [Input(f"marker-{i}", "position") for i in range(5)],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_markers(*positions):
    print('update_markers')
    return [create_marker(lat, lon, idx) for idx, (lat, lon) in enumerate(positions)]

# Callback to display the coordinates of markers
@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    [Input(f"marker-{i}", "position") for i in range(5)]
)
def display_coordinates(*positions):
    coordinates = [f"Marker {i}: {pos}" for i, pos in enumerate(positions)]
    return html.Ul([html.Li(coord) for coord in coordinates])

# Initial positions of markers to be set in layout
@app.callback(
    Output("layer", "children"),
    [Input("map", "children")],
    #prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def set_initial_positions(_):
    return [create_marker(lat, lon, idx) for idx, (lat, lon) in enumerate(initial_positions)]

# Run the Dash app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

I would expect the display_coordinates callback to be fired everytime a marker is dragged but it is not the case.
